# Firebase: Problem trying to delete document and return to previous screen

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to work out a way to

When viewing a document, I want to delete it, then return to the previous screen using `StackActions.pop(1)`.

My state is set up like this:

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [sensorData, setSensorData] = useState();

  const currentFarmId = useSelector((state) => state.session.currentFarm.farmId);
  const currentSensorId = useSelector((state) => state.session.currentSensor.sensorId);
```

I load data into sensorData like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    return db
      .collection('farms')
      .doc(currentFarmId)
      .collection('sensors')
      .doc(currentSensorId)
      .onSnapshot((documentSnapshot) => {
        const data = documentSnapshot.data();
        setSensorData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });

  }, [currentFarmId, currentSensorId]);s
```

Here's my delete code:

```
  function onDeleteSensorHandler() {
    deleteSensor()
      .then(() => {
        const afterDeleteNavigateAction = StackActions.pop(1);
        props.navigation.dispatch(afterDeleteNavigateAction);
      });
  }

  async function deleteSensor() {

    setLoading(true);

    await db
      .collection('farms')
      .doc(currentFarmId)
      .collection('sensors')
      .doc(currentSensorId)
      .delete();

    setLoading(false);

  }
```

And I render the screen like this:

```
  if (loading) {
    return <LoadingIndicator />;
  }

  // Render
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{sensorData.sensorType}</Text>
    </View>
```

My code properly deletes the document. The problem, however, is that I get an error:

`[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'sensorData.sensorType')]`

Which seems to suggest that React is trying to re-render the screen after the sensor has been deleted or something? Any ideas where the flaw in my code is?

Answer (score 1):

Is should be simple, `sensorData` is null or undefined and that is why you get the exception

simple edit the code above to this below should fix the issue

```
<Text>{sensorData?.sensorType}</Text>
```

Or make sure `sensorData` is never undefined

But if you look at the code, sensorData could be undefined

```
const [sensorData, setSensorData] = useState();
```